# How to make Chrome on Ubuntu ask to unlock the keyring on every form autofill?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

Using Chrome 118.0.5993.70 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Currently it doesn't ask me for a password or biometric identification at all (I might have disabled the unlock keyring popup on startup a while ago).

To prevent anyone who has access to my unlocked computer from all of the passwords stored in my browser, I'd like to re-identify (preferably with a fingerpring) every time a form is autofilled. Or even more importantly - every time I try to view my passwords in plain text.

Is this possible?
If not, what's a secure but convenient way to do autofill on Chrome/Ubuntu?

Comment: See this thread, which indicates other users have a similar, perhaps unresolvable issue. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2119312/password-autofill-even-when-logged-out?hl=en Perhaps another browser might provide more security.